# Sending video stream from 1 client to another in webapi c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am currently creating an application that acts like a network camera. What i had in mind is

- A client (probably silverlight, winforms) gets a frame from camera and send it to **WebAPI VIA HttpClient** as stream
- A server **WebAPI** will take the data  then send it to another client as stream
- Another client (silverlight, windows phone app, windows store app, WPF) will receive the data as stream

i tried **PushStreamContent** to view video asynchronously from from server to client based on this [Link](http://strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/) and it works but i dont know what to do upon sending from ***1 client to server then to client***.

Can anyone guide me to the right direction on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance..